# What is the meaning of "service-sector orientation" in the below sentence?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english

What is the meaning of "service-sector orientation" in the below sentence? It was taken from the IELTS reading test: https://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/Reading/IELTS_Reading_Passage_2.htm

> The land required for this service-sector orientation had been acquired in the early 1970s, when the government realized that it lacked the banking infrastructure for a modern economy. So a new banking and corporate district, known as the ‘Golden Shoe’, was planned, incorporating the historic commercial area.

What is the meaning of spontaneity in below sentence? Source is same.

> current concern also appears to be how to use the planning system to create opportunities for greater spontaneity:

Comment: What is the source of this quote, please

Comment: https://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/Reading/IELTS_Reading_Passage_2.htm

Comment: thank you, I'll edit into your question for you.

Comment: It's just the normal dictionary meaning of "spontaneity", action on an impulse or whim. Is there some reason you don't think that fits?

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather unusual usage of the word.  Looking at the wider context, it describes how Singapore made a decision in the latter half of the 20th century to change its business model from labour-intensive industries towards financial services.  This choice of "economic direction" could be called the "orientation" of the economy.  Singapore "oriented" its economic strategy towards banking services.

So the change of economic direction was "a service-sector orientation" of the Singapore economy.

(spontaneity is exactly the dictionary meaning)